# For Every Line in File Sum Values

Tags: perl

I am trying to make a Perl script that goes through and loops through a file, does some Regex to get number that are surrounded by parenthesis, add them up for every line.

```
#file
Awaiting_Parts_Bin(2),Inspection_Bin(1),Picked-1-3888(1),Picked-1-4364(2)
Picked-1-3890(1)
Picked-1-4364(1)
Picked-1-3888(4),Picked-1-3890(2),Picked-1-4364(1),Picked-1-7202(1)
Awaiting_Parts_Bin(1)
```

Desired Output

```
#new_file 
6
1
1
8
1
```

Perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = '/Users/.....csv';
my $new_file = '/Users/.....csv';

open(my $fh, '<', $file)
    or die "cannot open file";

open(my $new_fh, '>', $new_file)
    or die "cannot open file";



my $sum = 0;


while (my $line = <$fh>){
    my @arr = ( $line =~ /\(([0-9]+)\)/g);
    foreach my $val ( @arr ) { 
         $sum += $val;
         print  $sum, "\n";
         # this makes sense that it is resetting to zero while looping.  This is just one variation I tried. I tried putting the sum=0 outside the loop and it made it a running total
         $sum = 0;
    }
}
```

No matter what I try I can't get it right. This code doesn't add all of the values it takes the last one in the file.  So the output would look like this

```
#output now
2
1
1
1
1
```

Or if I remove the `$sum=0` in the for loop then it makes it a running total.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reset `$sum` to zero at the start of the *outer* (per line) `while` loop, not in the *inner* (per element) `foreach` loop.

This can be achieved by putting the declaration and initial assignment of `$sum` inside the `while` loop:

```
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    my $sum = 0;
    my @arr = ( $line =~ /\(([0-9]+)\)/g);
    foreach my $val ( @arr ) { 
         $sum += $val;
    }
    print $sum, "\n";
}
```

Comment: this give the total sum in one line

Comment: thats interesting. Any other thoughts on debugging? I copied and pasted your code. I went through and cleaned our carriage returns from file because I suspected that that might be the issue for a while

Comment: @nzaleski print the contents of `@arr` - perhaps your lines aren't terminated correctly and you're reading the entire file in one go?

Comment: yeah it they were not terminated correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use List::Util 'sum';

while ( <> ) {
    my $sum = sum /\((\d+)\)/g;
    print "$sum\n" if defined $sum;
}
```

#### output

```
6
1
1
8
1
```